# Existence of $(k,l)$-contraction map for tensors

Tags: tensor-calculus

**NOTE**: I've already asked this on Math SE, but since there were no responses over there and since Physics SE has GR and math experts as well, I thought I would ask it here. Please feel free to close the question if you guys think this question isn't right for Physics SE.

I'm studying about tensors and want to properly understand how the tensor index contraction rules are derived from first principles, rather than take them at face value. I have already understood the following theorem:

> If $V$ is a vector space, then $C^1_1$ is the unique linear function such that $C_1^1(v\otimes\eta)=\eta(v)=v(\eta)$ for all $v\in V$ and $\eta\in V^*$.

Now I'm reading about this theorem:

> Let $1\leq k\leq r, 1\leq l\leq s$. Then there exists a unique linear map $C^k_l:\mathcal{T}^r_s(V)\to\mathcal{T}^{r-1}_{s-1}(V)$ such that
> $$C^k_l(v_1\otimes\ldots\otimes v_r\otimes\eta^1\otimes\ldots\otimes\eta^s)=v_k(\eta^l)v_1\otimes\ldots\otimes \hat v_k\otimes\ldots\otimes v_r\otimes\eta^1\otimes\ldots\otimes\hat\eta^l\otimes\ldots\otimes\eta^s$$
> where the hat indicates that that term is omitted.

I first try proving every result and then check out the proof given in the book (Semi-Riemannian Geometry: The Mathematical Language of General Relativity by Newman). For the above theorem, my approach was substantially different from the book. Here's my attempt:

Let's define $$C^k_l(A)\equiv A^{i_1\ldots i_r}_{j_1\ldots j_s}\ C_1^1(h_{i_k}\otimes\theta^{j_l})\ h_{i_1}\otimes\ldots\otimes \hat h_{i_k}\otimes\ldots\otimes h_{i_r}\otimes\theta^{j_1}\otimes\ldots\otimes\hat\theta^{j_l}\otimes\ldots\otimes\theta^{j_s}$$ where $h_i$ and $\theta^j$ are basis vectors and dual basis respectively (the basis could be chosen arbitrarily). $A^I_J$ are of course the components of $A$ in the chosen basis. $C^k_l$ is well-defined since $C^1_1$ is well-defined due to the previous theorem.
With the above definition,
$$C^k_l(v_1\otimes\ldots\otimes v_r\otimes\eta^1\otimes\ldots\otimes\eta^s)$$
$$=(v_1)^{i_1}\ldots (v_r)^{i_r}(\eta^1)_{j_1}\ldots (\eta^s)_{j_s}C_1^1(h_{i_k}\otimes\theta^{j_l})\ h_{i_1}\otimes\ldots\otimes \hat h_{i_k}\otimes\ldots\otimes h_{i_r}\otimes\theta^{j_1}\otimes\ldots\otimes\hat\theta^{j_l}\otimes\ldots\otimes\theta^{j_s}$$
Pulling $(v_k)^{i_k}$ and $(\eta^l)_{j_l}$ into the $C_1^1$ argument and the rest of the components into the big tensor product on the right, we get the RHS of the desired result.

Uniqueness follows from the uniqueness of $C_1^1$.

Does the above proof look okay? Would greatly appreciate any help!

Comment: Crossposted from https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4351777/11127

Comment: @Qmechanic: Yep, I mentioned that in my question at the start. You can close it if it's not suitable for Physics SE